# Is it possible to run Xcode 6 beta 6 off a flash drive?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to run Xcode 6 beta 6 off of a flash drive or external hard drive? I tried to copy Xcode 6 beta 6 from my computer to a flash drive and then run it on a different computer. Xcode 6 beta 6 would not open from the flash drive.

Comment: Any error messages in *Console.app*?